# No (IOS Bundle Signing) option in Xamarin studio

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm an IOS developer in Xcode, but I still new to Xamarin environment ..

In **Xamarin Studio** on mac, I'm trying to run a simple app on my iPad, using [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/) ...

But when I come to this step :

[image]

I couldn't find this option (Build > **IOS Bundle Signing**), it looks like this :

[image]

The project is **IOS single view**, and I'm working using **Trial license** at the moment

So how could I get this option, to run the app on the device ??

And thanks in advance ..

Comment: Tu fais clique droit sur la solution et non sur le projet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clicked in the wrong node in the solution explorer

Instead of right-click the first node (the solution) right-click the second one (the project), there you will get the signing properties.